# Functions that change only for integers

Tags: functions, special-functions, integers

We all know there is floor function $[x]$ changes only for integers i.e.

$$[4]=[4.3]=[4.8]=4 ,[5]=5$$

I wonder if there are other functions that change only for integers? For instance we add $1$ for every integer to calculate floor function. So maybe we add $\ln x$ for every integer x to calculate "the function".

Note: I want a function that involves "elementary" functions like $log,sin,cos,...$

Comment: Well, but why down vote?

Comment: If you want a continuous function, then only constant functions satisfy your request.

Comment: @Crostul thanks for the information, I am removing that then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any function $\,f(x)\,$ that is not constant over the integers, then $\,f\left(\lfloor x \rfloor\right)\,$ will have [jump discontinuities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classification_of_discontinuities#Jump_discontinuity) at integer points. Below is for example the graph of [$\,\sin\left(\lfloor x \rfloor\right)\,$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin(%20floor(x)%20)%20,%200%20%3C%3D%20x%20%3C%3D%2020) .

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But the functions you've just presented involve "floor functions". It would be better if the functions does not involve floor function.

Comment: @BrightChancellor It also involves `"elementary" functions like log,sin,cos,...`. The question didn't say that no form of `floor` was permitted. You could look at $\cot(\pi x)$ for an example which has vertical asymptotes at each integer point, but other than that it's going to be hard to find an example of a function having just jump discontinuities at integers, and defined using *only* the smooth elementary functions.